# Local saving data from created div

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var d = document;
function add() {
  var div = d.getElementById("div"), txt = d.getElementById("txt"), name = d.getElementById("name");
  var newDiv = d.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = name.value + ('<br>') + txt.value;
  div.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.id = 'comment';
document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
document.getElementById("name").value = "";
}
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<br>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>

<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="add()">
<div id="div"></div>
```

This code creates div with id="comments" and post data from input and textarea in parent div with `id="div"`

And i cant realize how user data with created divs can be locally saved on client side by using local storage or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

First: try to avoid duplicated ids, use classes for multiple instances and add e.g. a position key to your I'd to make it unique (e.g. `class="comments"` `id="comment1"`). 
For storing logic you can find many tutorials in the Internet if you search for "local storage Javascript". In your example you can save an array on local storage with your data, e.g. 
`window.localStorage.setItem("divs", [...]);`

Or if you just want to know how much items were created, save the number of items.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good habit to put javascript at the bottom just before the closing body tag. This will give the dom chance to load before javascript is executed, making for example preloader very easy to implement.

Good resource for local storage, is [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Example of localStorage (taken from w3schools)

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Local storage is stored as string. This means you have to stringify objects. You can do so with json.stringify.

```
var myobject = {"foo":"bar"};
var mystring = JSON.stringify(myobject)
```

Good resource for cookies, again; [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Example of cookie (taken from w3schools)

```
document.cookie="username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

If you want to delete the cookie, you can set the date to value that has already passed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12048889)

Comment: @ManoDestra Nothing that can't be fixed ;) Consider the answer patched.